# How to add a third argument to google sheets countif function

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

=IF((COUNTIF(G3:M3;"Banana")>=1);"YES";"NO")

How can I add a third argument if G3:M3 is empty string I need "Nothing in your basket"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this using `IFS` instead of `IF`:

```
=IFS((COUNTIFS(G3:M3,"Banana") >=1),"YES",{G3:M3} = "","EMPTY",(COUNTIFS(G3:M3,"Banana") <=1 ),"NO")
```

**Output:**

[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use nested IFs to return multiple answers. Values can be replaced by functions that return values. Too many values can make for a nasty formula, but in your case it's pretty simple...

Example:
=IF(ISBLANK(G3:M3),"Nothing in your basket",IF(COUNTIF(G3:M3,"Banana")>=1,"YES","NO"))

Have fun!

Comment: Thanks, but it seems this is not working. Maybe because ISBLANK just returns True or FALSE. In my example even the empty cells return "NO"